# How to call two different functions for a same condition?

Tags: java, methods, graph

I have a Graph. At first it contains two edges `1 2` and `1 3` . If I go by the edge `1 2`, the method `testdata.firstData(s, t)` will be called where `s = 1` and `t = 2`.

Then I need to go through the edge `1 3` twice. So that first time the method `testdata.secondData(s, t)` and then `testdata.thirdData(s, t)` should be called.

So I have tried to do this like

```
if ("1".equals(s) && "2".equals(t))
    testinput = td.firstdata();
if ("1".equals(s) && "3".equals(t))
    testinput = td.seconddata();
```

But the problem is I don't know how to call the third method `testdata.thirdData(s, t)`. Can anyone give me any solution how can I call the second and third methods for the edge `1 3` ?

Comment: I think your design might a little off. What do these methods do? You could probably have one generic method to handle edges on a graph.

Comment: These methods returns some values and for each value each path of the graph will be executed. And I have 3 paths in my graph.One path starts with the edge "1 2" and the other two paths starts wilh "1 3".So to execute these 3 paths I need 3 values thats why I need to call 3 methods.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a [**block**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html): *A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.*

Comment: @Andreas can you give any example??

Comment: Example? Sure. Click the link and you'll see one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *boolean* flag to check whether or not the `seconddata()` method has already been called and use the `return` statement to quit the `TestData1()` method when needed.

```
boolean secondFinished = false;
public int TestData1(String a, String b){
TestdataGeneration td = new TestdataGeneration();

    if("1".equals(a) && "2".equals(b))
    {
        testinput = td.firstdata();
    }
    if("1".equals(a) && "3".equals(b) && !secondFinished)
    {
        testinput = td.seconddata();
        secondFinished = true;
        return testinput;
    }
    if("1".equals(a) && "3".equals(b) && secondFinished)
    {
         testinput = td.thirddata();
    }
    return testinput;
}
```

Or in a more readable fashion

```
boolean secondFinished = false;
public int TestData1(String a, String b){
TestdataGeneration td = new TestdataGeneration();

    if("1".equals(a) && "2".equals(b))
    {
        testinput = td.firstdata();
    }
    if("1".equals(a) && "3".equals(b))
    {
        if (!secondFinished)
        {
            secondFinished = true;
            return td.seconddata();
        }
        else
        {
            testinput = td.thirddata();
        }
    }
    return testinput;
}
```

Comment: `&` is bitwise and. `&&` is logical and. You want the logical and throughout your snippet.

Comment: Yeah true I just copied and pasted without checking

Comment: @AngeloOparah  Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted.